# Docker Angular Node Sass could not find a binding for your current env: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, mean-stack

I am trying do Dockerize a MEAN application and encounter an issue regarding the Angular container.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/custom_theme.scss
    angular_1         | Module build failed: Error: Missing binding /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
    angular_1         | Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
    angular_1         |
    angular_1         | Found bindings for the following environments:
    angular_1         |   - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
    angular_1         |
    angular_1         | This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
    angular_1         | Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
    angular_1         |     at module.exports (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    angular_1         |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    angular_1         |     at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    angular_1         |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    angular_1         |     at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    angular_1         |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    angular_1         |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    angular_1         |     at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    angular_1         |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    angular_1         |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    angular_1         |     at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    angular_1         |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    angular_1         |     at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    angular_1         |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    angular_1         |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    angular_1         |     at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    angular_1         |  @ ./src/custom_theme.scss 4:14-197
    angular_1         |  @ multi ./src/styles.css ./src/custom_theme.scss
```

I have tried to add `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to my dockerfile but without success. Here it is:

```
FROM node:8
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm rebuild node-sass --force
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?